# I am trying to login to my Netcomm Router/Modem and the password field is changing to base64 before it sends

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, login, modem, base64

I was recently seeing how the property of a family member faces out onto the internet and came across an issue in the netcomm login page. when I enter a password it changes it to Base64 before it sends the password to the device. this, therefore, means that the device is inaccessible. Has anyone else experienced the same issue and does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe that's normal for this router? Quite a few manufacturers use fancy JavaScript-based login pages which submit some sort of password hash instead of the plain password.

Comment: I haven't seen any mentions of this online and since that is not accepting the correct Username/Password combination then I believe that it either isn't this feature or the feature has broken